# Find the general solution and draw the phase portrait

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution and draw the phase portrait for the following
linear system:

$x_{1}^{\prime}=x_1$

$x_{2}^{\prime}=x_2$

My Procedure: 
The method of separation of variables can be used to solve the first-order
linear differential equation
$x^{\prime}=Ax$
where:
[ A = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1& 0  \\
 0 & 1 \end{array} \right|.] 
and the general solution is given by
$x(t)=c\epsilon^{at}$

so, the general solution of the uncoupled linear system can be found by the method of separation of variables. It is given by

$x_{1}^{\prime}=c_1\epsilon^{t}$

$x_{2}^{\prime}=c_2\epsilon^{t}$
or equivalently by

[ x(t) = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\epsilon^{t}& 0  \\
 0 & \epsilon^{t} \end{array} \right| c.]

but I can't draw the phrase portrait, I need your Help !

Comment: You have repeated eigenvalues $(1,1)$ and the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable. That means it's a proper node.

Comment: It is very confusing, I can't draw it, share with me a good book

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Typing `streamplot x,y` in [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) yields this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Exponential solution for each, as you got. Each phase portrait is its own straight line  through origin with constant slope as $ x_1, x_2 $ are not coupled.

Comment: It's a 45 degree line iff ${\mid c_1\mid} = {\mid c_2 \mid}$.